# Copy text from windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio

how can I copy selected by user text in other application to some variable in my app?
With using global hotke - user clicks hotkey, then my app will capture selected text in active window.

Comment: Why not just use the clipboard?

Comment: I don't have that text in clipboard - i wanna just capture selected text to my app with one hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

use ClipBoard.GetText() method

and this GetText method is having one parameter of predefind textdataformat

```
  public enum TextDataFormat
{
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that the text data is in the System.Windows.DataFormats.Text data
    //     format.
    Text = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that the text data is in the System.Windows.DataFormats.UnicodeText
    //     data format.
    UnicodeText = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that the text data is in the System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf data
    //     format.
    Rtf = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that the text data is in the System.Windows.DataFormats.Html data
    //     format.
    Html = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that the text data is in the System.Windows.DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue
    //     data format.
    CommaSeparatedValue = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that the text data is in the System.Windows.DataFormats.Xaml data
    //     format.
    Xaml = 5,
}

so if you know that data format is Text tha n


string text = ClipBoard.GetText(TextDataFormats.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the clipboard